# Footer row in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

What is the best way to put a footer row into a JTable? Does anyone have any sample code to do this?

The only approach I've thought of so far is to put a special row into the table model that always get sorted to the bottom.

---

Here is what I ended up with:

```
JTable mainTable = new JTable(mainTableModel);
JTable footerTable = new JTable(footerModel);
footerTable.setColumnModel(mainTable.getColumnModel());

// Disable selection in the footer. Otherwise you can select the footer row
// along with a row in the table and that can look quite strange.
footerTable.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
footerTable.setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);

JPanel tablePanel = new JPanel();
BoxLayout boxLayout = new BoxLayout(tablePanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
tablePanel.setLayout(boxLayout);
tablePanel.add(mainTable.getTableHeader()); // This seems like a bit of a WTF
tablePanel.add(mainTable);
tablePanel.add(footerTable);
```

Sorting works fine but selecting the footer row is a bit strange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using a second JTable that uses the same column model as your data table and add your footer data to that table. Add the second (footer) table under your original table.

```
JTable footer = new JTable(model, table.getColumnModel());
panel.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, table);
panel.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, footer);
```

Comment: This basically looks like a good solution, but it seems to react very oddly when you try to resize the columns.

Comment: This post helps sync the two tables
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666758/problem-with-resizing-columns-in-a-double-jtable

Comment: JideScrollPane works much better and avoids all of the problems of having to sync the events that the tables fire. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this [project](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/oss.htm) has a component called JideScrollPane which advertises support for a row footer. I haven't tried it myself, but it sounds like it does exactly what you want!
The website also has a demo app where you can see it in action and it that looks pretty good.

Note that it seems a lot of the their stuff you have to pay for, but their JideScrollPane looks to be free and open source.

Answer (score 1):

Using 2 tables below each-other is a good approach.

If you want to be able to resize/move/remove the colums, key is NOT to  reuse the same columnModel between the tables. Have a listener do the resizing. See example:

```
package snippet;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableColumnModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableColumnModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;

public class FixedRow2Tables extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4676303089799270571L;
    Object[][] data;
    Object[] column;
    JTable footerTable, table;

    public FixedRow2Tables() {
        super("Fixed Row Example");

        Object[][] mainData = new Object[][] { { "a", "", "", "", "", "" },
                { "", "b", "", "", "", "" }, { "", "", "c", "", "", "" },
                { "", "", "", "d", "", "" }, { "", "", "", "", "e", "" },
                { "", "", "", "", "", "f" } };
        Object[][] summaryData = { { "fixed1", "", "", "", "", "" },
                { "fixed2", "", "", "", "", "" } };
        column = new Object[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };

        table = new JTable(mainData, column);
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

        footerTable = new JTable(summaryData, column);
        footerTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        footerTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        footerTable.setTableHeader(null);
        // footerTable.setColumnModel(table.getColumnModel());

        table.getColumnModel().addColumnModelListener(
                new TableColumnModelListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void columnSelectionChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void columnRemoved(TableColumnModelEvent e) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void columnMoved(TableColumnModelEvent e) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void columnMarginChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                        final TableColumnModel tableColumnModel = table
                                .getColumnModel();
                        TableColumnModel footerColumnModel = footerTable
                                .getColumnModel();
                        for (int i = 0; i < tableColumnModel.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                            int w = tableColumnModel.getColumn(i).getWidth();
                            footerColumnModel.getColumn(i).setMinWidth(w);
                            footerColumnModel.getColumn(i).setMaxWidth(w);
                            // footerColumnModel.getColumn(i).setPreferredWidth(w);
                        }
                        footerTable.doLayout();
                        footerTable.repaint();
                        repaint();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void columnAdded(TableColumnModelEvent e) {
                    }
                });

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
        getContentPane().add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().add(footerTable, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                FixedRow2Tables frame = new FixedRow2Tables();
                frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 without `table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);`

Answer (score 0):

The only time I have done this I just added a row in the model like so:

```
    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return _tableContents.size() + 1;
    }
```

_tableContents is of course the actual data behind my model. You'll have to be aware of the extra row in the model of course (in such calls as setValueAt(...))

Good luck.

Comment: The only problem with that approach is sorting. I need the footer row to stay at the bottom of the table.

Comment: It is not just the sorting. Like a header, a footer might be expected to be visible all the time. So scrolling up and down behaves differently if the footer is just another row.

Answer (score 0):

You could try implementing your own [TableCellRenderer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html) that replaces the rendered content of the last visible row with your footer.  However this wouldn't be fixed at the bottom of the table, it will likely shift up and down as you scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best approach (but certainly not the easiest) would be to take a look at the source code for the `JTableHeader` Component, see how it works and then create your own `JTableFooter` Component. You can re-use the `JTableHeader` UI Delegate for the footer, I think the main differences would be in the `getHeaderRect()` method, where it determines the bounds of a given column header tile.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution mentioned in the [java bug database](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4242646)

> A solution that works for me is painting a border for the viewport (your JTable must be inside a JScrollPane) ....

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

class Application extends JFrame
{
    public Application()
    {
        this.setBounds(100,100,500,200);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        String data[][] = {{"a1","b1","c1"},{"a2","b2","c2"},{"a3","b3","c3"}};
        String columnNames[] = {"a","b","c"};

        JTable jtable = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(data,columnNames));

        JScrollPane jscrollPane = new JScrollPane(jtable,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        jscrollPane.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new MatteBorder(0,0,1,0,Color.gray),new EmptyBorder(0,0,0,0)));

        this.add(jscrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);


        JTable jtable_footer = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(3,columnNames.length),jtable.getColumnModel());

        SyncListener syncListener = new SyncListener(jtable,jtable_footer);

        this.add(jtable_footer,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                Application application = new Application();

                application.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

class SyncListener implements TableColumnModelListener
{
    JTable jtable_data;
    JTable jtable_footer;

    public SyncListener(JTable main, JTable footer)
    {
        jtable_data = main;
        jtable_footer = footer;

        DefaultTableColumnModel dtcm = (DefaultTableColumnModel)jtable_data.getColumnModel();

        dtcm.removeColumnModelListener(dtcm.getColumnModelListeners()[1]);
        dtcm.addColumnModelListener(this);
    }

    public void columnMarginChanged(ChangeEvent changeEvent)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < jtable_data.getColumnCount(); column++)
        {
            jtable_footer.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).setWidth(jtable_data.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).getWidth());
        }

        jtable_footer.repaint();
    }

    public void columnAdded(TableColumnModelEvent e){}
    public void columnMoved(TableColumnModelEvent e){}
    public void columnRemoved(TableColumnModelEvent e){}
    public void columnSelectionChanged(ListSelectionEvent e){}
}
```