# Java: lambda local variable declaration issue

Tags: java, lambda

I'm following the example in the answer at [JavaFX TableView Sort Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25509031/javafx-tableview-sort-policy) to do my own comparator, but lambda expressions are new to me and I'm having trouble understanding what's going on.

What works is ugly:

```
    elementsTable.sortPolicyProperty().set(t -> {
        Comparator<Row> comparator = (r1, r2)
            -> of.wrap.els.getElement(toZ(r1.getSymbol())).getZ() > 
                    of.wrap.els.getElement(toZ(r2.getSymbol())).getZ() ? 1
            : of.wrap.els.getElement(toZ(r1.getSymbol())).getZ() < 
                    of.wrap.els.getElement(toZ(r2.getSymbol())).getZ() ? -1
            : of.wrap.els.getElement(toZ(r1.getSymbol())).getZ() == 
                    of.wrap.els.getElement(toZ(r2.getSymbol())).getZ() ? 0
            : t.getComparator() == null ? 0 //no column sorted: don't change order
            : t.getComparator().compare(r1, r2); //columns are sorted: sort accordingly
            FXCollections.sort(elementsTable.getItems(), comparator);
        return true;
    });
```

But if I try

```
    int n1,n2;
    elementsTable.sortPolicyProperty().set(t -> {
        Comparator<Row> comparator = (r1, r2)
            ->
            n1 = of.wrap.els.getElement(toZ(r1.getSymbol())).getZ();
            n2 = of.wrap.els.getElement(toZ(r2.getSymbol())).getZ();
            n1 > n2 ? 1
            : n1 < n2 ? -1
            : n1 == n2 ? 0
            : t.getComparator() == null ? 0 //no column sorted: don't change order
            : t.getComparator().compare(r1, r2); //columns are sorted: sort accordingly
            FXCollections.sort(elementsTable.getItems(), comparator);
        return true;
    });
```

NetBeans indicates that r2 is unused in the comparator, and all instances of r1 and r2 are flagged as undefined in scope, excepting the first r1 as part of n1.

If I try to declare the n1, n2 internally as int it gives "'.class' expected", or -> becomes an illegal start of expression if final.

What's the correct way to do what I'm trying?

Comment: need `{}`   `(params)->{  statements   }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign variables outside the scope of the Lambda expression, and you need to put multiple statements in brackets:

```
elementsTable.sortPolicyProperty().set(t -> {
    Comparator<Row> comparator = (r1, r2) -> {
        int n1 = of.wrap.els.getElement(toZ(r1.getSymbol())).getZ();
        int n2 = of.wrap.els.getElement(toZ(r2.getSymbol())).getZ();
        return n1 > n2 ? 1
        : n1 < n2 ? -1
        : n1 == n2 ? 0
        : t.getComparator() == null ? 0 //no column sorted: don't change order
        : t.getComparator().compare(r1, r2); //columns are sorted: sort accordingly
        };
        FXCollections.sort(elementsTable.getItems(), comparator);
    return true;
});
```

You can avoid the insane nested-ness by making the comparator a constant outside of the outer lambda. Also note that the last two `: t.getComparator()...` will never be reached.

Comment: I took those from the example, wasn't sure how they ever would be but left them in.  Is there a resource you can point me to that explains the internal return there?

Comment: I'd need to look one up, but as a rule-of-thumb you can imagine the brackets like the brackets of a method body, in which you also need a return statement.

Comment: Thanks, this answer did a lot to help me understand this and implement comparators for a handful of other objects as well, and without the said insane nesting.