# How to set fixed footer in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a Java Swing application, I want create a JTable with fixed footer, but I think in Java Swing there isn't this possibility.
This is my Jtable:

```
jScrollPaneMovimenti = new JScrollPane();
tableModelConti = new MyTableModelContiSpeseEntrate();
tableConti = new CustomTableSpeseEntrateXConti(tableModelConti);
tableConti.addKeyListener(new MyKeyListenerSalvataggio());
tableConti.setRowHeight(25);
jScrollPaneMovimenti.setViewportView(tableConti);
jScrollPaneMovimenti.setPreferredSize(dTabellaConti);
```

I don't want to insert a JPanel with two table because I use the last row of my table to do a calculations.
It's possible to do this?

Comment: There is no such option in JTable but there are workarounds to achieve this. Refer the post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978865/footer-row-in-a-jtable

Comment: I don't want to insert a JPanel with two table because I use the last row of my table to do a calculations. It's possible to do this? == (because I use the last row of my table to do a calculations) ---> search here about TableColumnModelListener :-)